Question on Kronecker lemma
Let $\{x_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\{a_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers satisfying $a_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$. Further, suppose $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_n}{a_n}$ converges. Then, show that
$
\frac{1}{a_n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k \to 0 \quad \text{as } n \to \infty.
$
This post in the comments says that this is reformulation of Kronecker lemma and Kronecker lemma is bit different so what is that modification

Hint: rename $x_n$ in your problem or Wikipedia's theorem statement, then choose the sequences in the theorem in terms of those in your problem.

please elaborate more
